# Can't help dividing thread work with OpenMP, doing one instruction with a single thread and a parallel for with the remaining

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, pthreads, openmp

I post the current version of my code, which is this one

```
#   pragma omp parallel
{ 
...
...
...
#   pragma omp single nowait   
   for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { 
       centroids[points[i].cluster].points_in_cluster++;
   }
   

   for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { //I want thread_count - 1 to be working here
#       pragma omp for
       for (int coord = 0; coord < N; coord++){
           //int my_tid = omp_get_thread_num();
           //printf("my tid:%d my_coord: %d my i:%d\n ", my_tid, coord, i);
           centroids[points[i].cluster].accumulator.coordinates[coord] += points[i].coordinates[coord];
       }
   }
#   pragma omp barrier
...
...
...
}
```

and works fine already, but I want to see if times can be improved by doing the following, make one thread do what is under the `omp single` pragma, and the other do what is underneath, without his help. So if there are 8 threads, 1 will do the `single` section, and 7 the other part.

I tried with `omp sections` but it didn't work, because it said that `work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing`.

Comment: `#pragma omp single nowait` does exactly what you what, one thread is working on that section and other threads start the for loop. Another alternative is using tasks.

Comment: @Laci that's right, but I want that one thread who is working on his single task to NOT work on the #omp for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tasks to solve your problem. In this case one thead will run the first loop, all other threads the second loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    #pragma omp task
    {
        // one task (thread) runs this part of the code
    }
    
    #pragma omp taskloop num_tasks(omp_get_num_threads()-1)
    for (....){
        // all other tasks (threads) run this loop
    }
}
```

By the way, I don't think this code would run faster compared to the other approach, since the overhead of using tasks is higher.

Comment: thank you. But what is the meaning of that omp single? Is it that each task should be executed by one thread? And then the taskloop directive says that this one task should be executed by multiple threads? Thanks

Comment: `omp single` used to make sure that only a single thread will generate tasks. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502197/how-do-omp-single-and-omp-task-provide-parallelism) and/or these documents [1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/sc13.tasking.ruud.pdf), [2](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs575/Handouts/tasks.1pp.pdf). Taskloop is also a task generating construct explained e.g here: [1](https://hpc2n.github.io/Task-based-parallelism/branch/master/task-basics-2/), [2](https://blog.rwth-aachen.de/itc-events/files/2021/02/09-openmp-CT-taskloop.pdf)