Running DO loop and independent subroutine calls in parallel in OpenMP
Is there an efficient way in openmp to do the following:
While a do-loop is executing in parallel using openmp, call two or more subroutines that can run independently and parallel with the loop.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

ps: Using sections and creating sub-processes is too slow. The subroutines call gpus for computations independent (and outside) those of the loop. Overlapping them without creating/destroying subprocesses would lead to substantial gains.
example:
!$OMP  PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)
!$OMP DO
  Do I = 1, N
     ... compute stuff in here
  End Do
!$OMP END DO   
!$OMP END PARALLEL

 Call GPU_1
 Call GPU_2
 Call GPU_3
 Call GPU_4

While the loop is executing, must run the calls to the gpu. As i noted, creating and destroying threads in SECTIONs is too slow.
Edit: Thank you for your suggestions. The do loop is computationally heavy (no sub calls just calculations) and do not see how to insert the four gpu calls to run in parallel with the do loop.
I did try sections where one section contains the do loop and creates sub-processes specifically for the do loop but that shows no speed-up benefits.
It is not clear how the tasks will achieve this. I may have missed the point.

Sounds like a job for tasks or/and nested parallelism. Can you show some example code?

Most OpenMP implementations reuse threads for a single level of parallel regions. With nested parallel regions, some implementations destroy threads for the inner level. The LLVM runtime has a default setting KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MAX_LEVEL=1. If you increase the level, you can reuse also threads from the inner parallel region.

With this setting you can have an outer parallel/sections region with two threads, have one section executing your parallel region and the other section execute your subroutines. A possible issue with this approach: the target regions created from the subroutines will synchronize with the implicit barrier at the end of the outer parallel region.

Welcome. I suggest taking the [tour] around the site. I also recommend showing some example code, seeing an example can help tremendously.

Well tasks look as though thy could do this - drop the !$omp do. make the body of the loop a task and also make the subroutines that can be done at the same time tasks. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502197/how-do-omp-single-and-omp-task-provide-parallelism - take note of the use of !$omp single!

BTW why do you think sections will create processes? Nothing in OMP creates or destroys processes. And worksharing constructs like section will not even create any new threads.

With OpenMP 6.0 (check out the latest TR for reference) you will be able to use free-agent tasks for this purpose. Just wrap the subroutine call into a task with threadset(pool). Then start your parallel region.

Suggestion:
!$OMP  PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)

!$OMP SINGLE
   Call GPU_1
   Call ...
!$OMP END SINGLE NOWAIT

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(nonmonotic:dynamic)
  Do I = 1, N
     ... compute stuff in here
  End Do
!$OMP END DO
   
!$OMP END PARALLEL

One thread starts executing the GPU stuff, and thanks to the NOWAIT clause the other threads go on and execute the loop. The dynamic scheduling is required to allow these threads to handle all the iterations, even if the thread that executes the GPU stuff takes more time.
Alternatively, the do loop can be executed by a TASKLOOP, which naturally handles all the iterations with the available threads:
!$OMP  PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)

!$OMP SINGLE
   Call GPU_1
   Call ...
!$OMP END SINGLE NOWAIT

!$OMP SINGLE
!$OMP TASKLOOP
  Do I = 1, N
     ... compute stuff in here
  End Do
!$OMP END TASKLOOP
!$OMP END SINGLE

!$OMP END PARALLEL

In both case one thread is maybe mostly inactive during the GPU calls. This could be mitigated by launching one more thread, so that all cores are always occupied:
nt = omp_get_max_threads() + 1

!$OMP  PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) NUM_THREADS(nt)

!$OMP SINGLE
   Call GPU_1
   Call ...
!$OMP END SINGLE NOWAIT

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(nonmonotic:dynamic)
  Do I = 1, N
     ... compute stuff in here
  End Do
!$OMP END DO
   
!$OMP END PARALLEL


Here's how you might attempt it using tasks:
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran-12 --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright © 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat task.f90
Program taskit

  Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_thread_num, omp_get_num_threads
  
  Implicit None

  Integer :: i

  !$omp parallel default( none )

  !$omp single

  Write( *, * ) 'Using ', omp_get_num_threads(), ' threads'

  !$omp task
  Call sub1
  !$omp end task

  !$omp task
  Call sub2
  !$omp end task

  !$omp task
  Call sub3
  !$omp end task

  !$omp task
  Call sub4
  !$omp end task

  Do i = 1, 40
     !$omp task
     Write( *, * )' In loop ', omp_get_thread_num()
     !$omp end task
  End Do

  !$omp end single

  !$omp end parallel

Contains

  Subroutine sub1

    Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_thread_num
  
    Implicit None

    Write( *, * ) 'Hello from thread ', omp_get_thread_num(), ' in sub1'
    
  End Subroutine sub1
  
  Subroutine sub2

    Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_thread_num
  
    Implicit None

    Write( *, * ) 'Hello from thread ', omp_get_thread_num(), ' in sub2'
    
  End Subroutine sub2
  
  Subroutine sub3

    Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_thread_num
  
    Implicit None

    Write( *, * ) 'Hello from thread ', omp_get_thread_num(), ' in sub3'
    
  End Subroutine sub3

  Subroutine sub4

    Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_thread_num
  
    Implicit None

    Write( *, * ) 'Hello from thread ', omp_get_thread_num(), ' in sub4'
    
  End Subroutine sub4

  
End Program taskit
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran-12 -std=f2018 -fcheck=all -Wall -Wextra -g -fopenmp task.f90 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ 

And running it a few times
jb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Using            8  threads
 Hello from thread            4  in sub1
  In loop            5
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            1
  In loop            6
  In loop            3
 Hello from thread            0  in sub3
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            5
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
 Hello from thread            7  in sub2
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            7
  In loop            1
  In loop            0
  In loop            3
  In loop            6
  In loop            5
 Hello from thread            2  in sub4
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Using            8  threads
 Hello from thread            4  in sub1
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            0
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            4
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
  In loop            3
 Hello from thread            7  in sub3
  In loop            0
  In loop            7
  In loop            2
  In loop            4
 Hello from thread            1  in sub4
 Hello from thread            6  in sub2
  In loop            3
  In loop            5
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ 


The problem with doing everything with tasks here is that there's -in theory- no guarantee that the tasks that are created first are executed first. Which can be a problem in case the "sub1" "sub2" etc take more wall time than the loop. Admittedly, in practice I can't see why a compiler would not assign the tasks in the order they are created (in the absence of any depend clause), so it should not be a problem in practice.
